Listing declined invitation to conferences in CV (because of agenda clash)
I am currently in 3rd year of post-doc.
I have presented my work at a reasonable amount of conferences (I think my CV is sufficiently good with this aspect). Yet, while I have been invited to a good amount of seminars, I only had very few invitations to present my work at workshop or conferences.
To be specific, I have been invited to present my work at two workshops, and one international conference (to be given in a few months). I had to decline one of the two workshop invitation because it was in the middle of crucial deadlines for grant applications for which I was already late (I received the invitation to the workshop quite late).
I have recently been invited to organize and moderate a panel on a topic of which I am expert at a quite prestigious conference occuring in February.
The problem is that the event occurs at a moment when it is impossible for me to attend (wedding of a very close relative the day before, I wouldn't have time to take the plane as the conference is on the other side of the planet).
I am quite frustrated by this because the conference is prestigious and it would have been an excellent way to demonstrate my scientific visibility. Also, it is the second declined invitation in the workshop/conference category on my CV, so even more annoying. It is important that I can defend a bit more the "invitation to conferences" aspect on my CV given the fact I am applying to permanent jobs.
Hence, I would like to list this conference on my CV, still, and explain why I couldn't attend (in a footnote: I guess anyone could reasonably understand the reason). I could justify my invitation by putting a link toward a PDF that shows explicitly the invitation email I received.
I emphasize on:

This is really not "CV padding" (i.e. putting additional poorly relevant stuff on your CV to make it look longer) because this line would be among the strongest points appearing on the conference section of my CV.
I will explain directly in my CV why I could not attend and put a justification of the invitation (the link to the pdf aforedmentioned).

My question:
From the perspective of a jury recruiting permanent researchers, is it ok to list this on the CV? In particular, does it fulfill my goal of demonstrating scientific visibility/recognition (in my opinion, yes as the fact I did not present is entirely irrelevant to this aspect), but maybe it is bad practice to do so.
I have seen various contradictory explanations about this on this website, see here and here, so I am confused.
If there is an objective reason why it is bad, I would like to understand the reason why (I am not sure to understand the argument which say it is a bad idea, but maybe these arguments do not apply in my context).

This might depend on your field, so I will answer for my own field (in the environmental sciences).
No, a declined invitation to organise a panel at a conference is not something that should go on your CV. It would definitely be considered padding. Organising a panel or session at a conference is a volunteer service to the community rather than a measure of prestige — and in this case it is a service that you were not able to perform.
If you get in touch with the organisers of the next relevant conference in your field and offer to organise something similar, there’s a good chance your offer will be accepted, and you can put that on your CV once you start work on the preparations.
If you had been invited to present a keynote or plenary at a prestigious conference but weren’t able to attend, I’d see that as more of a dilemma.

I agree that presenting your own work at a prestigious conference is different, arguably, better than being invited to organize + moderate an expert panel. However why do you think that doing this is "a detail" that should not go on the CV? Doesn't it demonstrates a good international visibility? In particular because a panel is a central event of a conference, and it will be clear that I was invited purely because of scientific visibility in this case. I am saying this because I am not affiliated at all with the organizers and the conference is organized on the other side of the world, [...]

i.e. it is not like I'm helping to organize a local event (in this case I would agree that this would be a minor thing on the CV because it would be natural that I help organizing it)

In my field, even for the big international conferences, this is a matter of service to the community and is done by volunteers. It does belong in the CV if you actually do it, but not if you declined a request.

Ok. Thank you !
